# To Calculate Average Value of Multiple Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to calculate the Average value of multiple ranges as shown in attached Fig.
Conditions -
It should match the cell value of column "L" and "M" with a range of column "A"  and Make a range (e.g 322810 to 324900) to calculate the average of column B values which are against the specific range (e.g 322810 to 324900).
I've been able to write the following code but it obviously not working.

```
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim i As Long, j As Long

 With Worksheets("Source")
 lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lastrow + 1 'loop whole range (column C)
    If .Cells(i, "L") = .Range("A").Value Then 'If column L cell value match with any cell of Range "A"
        For j = i To lastrow 'Loop "group" range.
            If .Cells(j, "M") = .Range("A").Value Then ' (end of small group range) then apply formula
                .Cells(i, "N").Formula = "=AVERAGE(B" & i & ":B" & j & ")" 'AVG
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next I
End With
```

All kind of help will be appreciated (Formula or VBA Code)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Use AVERAGEIFS and skip the VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BigBen is right. This is the way. The Formula in my example is

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B$3:$B$16,$A$3:$A$16,">="&L4,$A$3:$A$16,"<="&M4)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There will be Comma (,) instead of Semi-column (;) between the criteria....Thank you very much @Wolfgang

Comment: Ah yes @surendrachoudhary, that was due to my local settings (german)

Comment: Corrected the original post now @surendrachoudhary, thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim mPoint As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range
    Dim rngDB As Range
    
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Source")


    With Ws
        Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        vDB = .Range("L3", .Range("m" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        r = UBound(vDB, 1)
        ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 1)
 
        For i = 1 To r
            For k = 1 To Lastrow
                If .Range("a1").Cells(k) = vDB(i, 1) Then
                    Set rngStart = .Range("a1").Cells(k)
                    mPoint = rngStart.Row
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
            If rngStart Is Nothing Then
            Else
                For k = mPoint To Lastrow
                    If .Range("a1").Cells(k) = vDB(i, 2) Then
                        Set rngEnd = .Range("a1").Cells(k)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
            
            If rngStart Is Nothing Or rngEnd Is Nothing Then
            Else
               Set rngDB = .Range(rngStart, rngEnd).Offset(, 1)
               Debug.Print rngDB.Address
                vR(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Average(rngDB)
            End If
            Set rngStart = Nothing
            Set rngEnd = Nothing
        Next i
        .Range("n3").Resize(r) = vR
    End With

End Sub
```